# Sampling from an R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

I have a dataframe with various real estate listings similar to the following.

```
ADDRESS      PRICE     ZIP     ...
123 Main St  400,000   45678
23 Green Ln  380,000   45670
29 Green Ln  385,000   45670
...
```

I want to perform a stratified random sample for a testing dataset. In other words, I want to take ~30% of the entries from each ZIP code and separate them into a new dataset. I am not familiar with R dataframes, so how would I perform such an operation?

I've used the sample function like so

```
sample(c(1:103), size=31, replace = F)
```

but how do I put these specific rows into a new dataframe?

```
8  85   5  83  66  46  39  75 101  94  10  68  63  74  22  86  42
59  52  97  62  11  44  96  88  28   9  36   2  78  49
```

Comment: You can use `sample()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a stratified sampling you can use the [`createDataPartition`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/createDataPartition) function from the `caret` package by inserting the variable according to which you want to stratify (in your case `ZIP`). By using `[[1]]` you select the first element of the list which contains the row indices necessary for the split. Afterwards, you subset your original dataset by select only the rows given by `train_index`

```
train_index <- caret::createDataPartition(your_data$ZIP, p = 0.7)[[1]]
train_data <- your_data[train_index,]
test_data <- your_data[-train_index,]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` solution would be this one I believe:

```
train_set <- df %>%
  group_by(ZIP) %>%
  sample_frac(0.3)
```

It will return a dataframe with sample values for each ZIP group